# Language resulting in the same NFA as the DFA

Tags: automata, finite-automata

I have tried to construct the NFA and DFA from the same language term, and they keep coming out the same, I was wondering if this is correct for:

{w | w has an even length and an odd number of a's}
 such that w contains characters from $\{a,b\}$.

[image: my answer]

Comment: That looks correct for a DFA. And I think every DFA is also an NFA.

Comment: it looks correct.

Comment: That's what I thought and I literally cannot think of a way to make them differ from each other.

Comment: You can always join two independent automata together in an appropriate way :-).

Comment: It looks correct, and, yes, DFAs are NFAs.

Comment: There is no such thing as "the NFA of a language". What do you mean by that?